# dell built in keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, dell, keyboard-layout

im using **dell** ***inspiron 11 3179*** and dual booting linux, but it doesnt matter
the problem is the keyboard shortcut, so im playing minecraft on my linux. in minecraft the  key to open **debug screen** is `f3`, but in this laptop the `f3` is for volume up. in windows it doesnt effecting the game cause you need to press `ctrl` or `fn` key(mine use the `ctrl`) to use the `f"number"` shortcut. but linux has a different way to do it, cause you only need to press the `f3` only and the volume is rising. at first i think this is cool, but when i played minecraft i cant use the button cause it used to rise the volume, and i dont know how to fix this
pls someone who knows something, can you help me?.
sorry for my english, thanks

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: You need FN+F3 obviously. And I seriously doubt it's different in Windows as this new fad of inverting the main and secondary functions of the functions keys is set in the firmware (UEFI) and often but not always it can be toggled off, again, in UEFI, it's unrelated with the OSes.

Comment: i use 21.4, gnome 3.38.5 wayland system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a laptop. Your laptop is configured to access the function keys when pressing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. Thus, hit <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to issue an F3 keypress instead of increasing the volume.

You can change this behavior in your computer BIOS. See the manual of your model to learn how to boot into BIOS. After the change, you will need to hit <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to change the volume.

On some laptops, notably also Dell, that behavior can be switched by hitting <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>. The change is in effect for the current session only, and will be reset to the BIOS default on next boot.

Comment: just to need enter need bios right?

Comment: and if i already in the bios what should i do

Comment: That is not about Ubuntu but about your specific hardware. There probably will be a setting to change the default behaviour. Otherwise, you can just remember to use Fn+Esc before starting the game.

Comment: ik this is not about ubuntu as you say that, but i'm not a professional about computing
thats why i  ask you, btw iyou dont need to answer this again, i gonna search it by myself. thank you very much, you already help me a lot, thanks for your help and sorry for bad english